Why do Derivatives require 1 input whereas Integrals require 2?
My little bro asked me this interesting question. He's 15.
Like if you want to do a Derivative of an equation you only have to input 1 number as you are calculating the slope of that one point.
In the case of Integrals, you have to input a range, as you are calculating the area under the equation from suppose point "a to b".
He had thought of this question when he saw that for doing derivative and integrals in a basic Scientific calculator like the Casio 991-ex, you have to input 1 and 2 numbers.
I just gave him this explanation, but My question is,
Is there a more Intuitive way to think of this?
Like I want to visualize this in my head. Like This. Here we can sort of visualize what happens when to derivate/integrate an equation.
Same way i want to visualize why you only need 1 input for Derivation and 2 for Integrating.
[Note: This is my first question, So, I apologize for the messy formatting]

Evaluating an integral at one point doesn't make sense since an integral isn't a function...it's only determined up to an (unknown) additive constant so you could just pick any value.  If you evaluate it at two points, however, then the difference is well defined (as the constant cancels out).

One way to explain this is: taking the derivative is a "machine" that takes in functions and outputs a function. However, it turns out that if we try to find a machine that "reverses" the derivative machine, we can't find one. For example, all the constant functions go to the same function $0$. In general, if $f$ is a function and $c$ a constant, then $f$ and $f+c$ differentiate to the same function.
But actually, it turns out that this is the only problem! In other words, we can almost reverse the process: given a function $g$, we can find* one representative $f$ such that all the functions that differentiate to $g$ look like $f+c$. This has a small issue: two reversing machines might give different $f$s for the same $g$. One way to fix this is, as you can guess, give another input $a$, and demand that the $f$ you get satisfies, say, $f(a)=0$. Notice that we really have "two number inputs" here, as we might as well have demanded $f(a)=b$ for any $b$. So, you definitely need two "special numbers" to fix a particular output. Another way which is just more used, is to return instead $f(b)-f(a)$.

This idea definitely appears frequently. For example, in groups (or some other nice category if you wish, whatever that means), if I have a group homomorphism $f\colon G\to H$, it is a very simple thing -- it takes a input and gives an output. But to reverse it, one input might not be enough! If the kernel is nontrivial, then multiple things go to the identity. So, one can specify the inverse function only "upto some element of the kernel". In fact, you could realise the derivative as a group homomorphism from the set of all differentiable functions to the set of all functions** with the additive group structure, then the kernel is the constant function. Definite integral is one way to fix the inverse definitely (pun intended), which would otherwise involve a choice.
*Not all functions, but not relevant here.
**The codomain should really be something else, but that's not relevant here.
Hope this helps. :>
